# Relation between math and piano music

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, fractals, music-theory

What, if any, is the relation between Cantor's function and Ligeti studio: Devil's Staircase?

Comment: This is not an appropriate forum for your question.  I've voted to close.

Comment: This *is* a legitimate question since Ligeti's etude seems to be
specifically inspired by the mathematical function (see
http://monashcomposers.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/ligeti-13-page1.png
for the start, and hear http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZTaiDHqs5s
for the whole thing).  It might even belong on mathoverflow, at least
as a reference request for a published exploration of this connection.

Comment: A few minutes on Google turn up "On Musical Self-Similarity"
by Di Gabriel Pareyón, which reports on p.359 that the piece was
written "under the advice of mathmeatician Heinz-Otto Peitgen"
and "exhibits recursive qualities, whilst its hemiola rhythmic cells of 
2 to 3 recall the binary-ternary geometry of the devil's staircase."
That's a start, and maybe there's a more thorough exploration
to be found.

Comment: [Oops, I didn't notice that this had already been answered $-$
I might have noticed that the scroll bar indicated an extension
below the "put on hold as off-topic" block]

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141082/what-is-mazzolas-topos-of-music-about

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a Masters thesis by Lauren Halsey entitled,
"An examination of rhythmic practices and influences in the keyboard works of György Ligeti"
([UNCG link](http://libres.uncg.edu/ir/uncg/listing.aspx?id=8634)), which addresses your question:

> "...the idea for this etude emerged: “an endless 
>   climbing, a wild apocalyptic vortex, a staircase it was almost impossible to ascend.”<sup>28</sup>
>   This etude shares the name and characteristics of the mathematical concept of a “devil’s 
>   staircase.” This phenomenon, based on Cantor Sets, involves the relationship of 
>   disproportional segments combining to create a self-similar group.<sup>29</sup> This concept is also 
>   used in the “mode locking” features of clocks and pendulums.<sup>30</sup> Ligeti expresses this 
>   concept with the inclusion of groups of two and three eighth notes that, when combined, 
>   create a self-similar rhythmic set. This grouping structure creates pulse streams and 
>   defines the formal boundaries of this piece. The structures seem to spiral infinitely up the 
>   piano, suddenly falling down to the lowest octaves.<sup>31</sup>

---

[image: Figure 4.4]

---

And here is a graph from [Wikipedia's Cantor function article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) of the Devil's Stairase:

 [image: Cantor Graph]

Comment: I followed your link @Joseph and found Halsey thesis. Nice work, in pages 51-54 we can see Ligeti's concern about chaos and fractals and how he developed this etude. Thanks for your reference.